# How can $T(n) = T(0.8*n) + O(n)$ run $O(n)$ based on Master Theorem?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I am learning to calculate the time complexity.

$T(n) = T(0.8*n) + O(n)$

I come across the equation above. And based on Master Theorem, it falls under case $3$ where $a < b$.
The solution to this says it is $O(n)$. But how does it become $O(n)$?
Here is the pseudocode...

```
func(int n) {
   if (n == 0) return 1;
   for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      a++;
   }
   func(0.8*n);
}
```

Could you please explain it in detail? Thank you very much.

Comment: This may be unrelated as it’s not really a mathematical criticism, but where is `a` defined? How can you be certain that a function which only accepts integer inputs will accept `0.8*n`?

Comment: I have a little math skills. I understand your questions like this.
For the first question, `a` is defined in 1 * T(0.8*n).
For the second question, `0.8 * n` will give float number, right? In my calculation, I use floor (0.8 * 8 = 6).

Comment: I meant the `a` in the code, not the constant $a$ from the master theorem. Regardless, it’s not relevant. This may be nitpicking, but if the calculation uses $\lfloor 0.8 n\rfloor,$ then the recurrence should be written as $$T(n) = T(\lfloor 0.8 n\rfloor) + \mathcal{O}(n).$$ However, I understand that this is a common abuse of notation.

Comment: Ahhh it is O(n) * O(1). I removed it because it is constant time. And also I didn't initialize it, my bad.
And again so sorry, I don't know how to type floor notation in StackExchange.

I just want to know when I come across the T(n) similar to this, I will be able to analyze it correctly.

Comment: No worries, you can visit the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see how to properly typeset math for future use. Someone has already been kind enough to make an edit to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of this third case of the Master Theorem is that if the work in the invidual steps shrinks 'rapidly enough', then the work that has to be done at the 'top level' (at $n$) dominates the complexity (in order of magnitude).

This is easy enough to work out without using the Master Theorem. Say $T(n) \leq T(0.8 n) + c n$ for some constant $c$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
T(n) & \leq c n + T(0.8 n) \\
& \leq c n + c 0.8 n + T(0.8^2 n) \\
& \leq c n + c 0.8 n + c 0.8^2 n + T(0.8^3 n) \\
& \leq \dots \\
& \leq c(1 + 0.8 + 0.8^2 + \dots) n \\
& = \frac{cn}{1 - 0.8} \\
& = 5cn.\end{align*}$$

So, indeed $T(n) = O(n)$. There is of course the extra factor $5$, but that disappears in the $O$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I understand now.

Comment: However, How about using Master Theorem? Could you also add the steps related to it?

Comment: What do you mean? You have yourself already applied the Master Theorem in your question: you wind up in what you call the third case and the complexity is $O(n)$.

Comment: Ahhh... I am sorry. I forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation can be a little tricky. The reason something like that is considered Big O(n), is because that is the dominant force in your recurrence relation. The subproblems are broken into O(.8n) every loop, but when considering time complexity, big O is only the dominant force. If we break down this functions complexity, it would look like this:
$$
O(n) + O(.8n) + O(.64n) + O(.512n) + ...
$$
on and on, since each time its only getting split once by .8 of the last iterations size. Now we can see that O(n) is the largest of those, and therefore the time complexity is O(n). Another example would be if we had an algorithm that costs
$$n^2 + \log n + n$$
we would say the time complexity is $O(n^2)$ because that is the dominant force.